Get ASP.NET Core Identity auth cookie name
During startup, I configure the Identity auth cookie:
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x =>
{
  x.Cookie.Name = "foo";    // default is ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application"
  // other config...
});

I need that cookie's info during runtime, so in some controller I inject IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, and then try get the cookie name:
var cookieName = cookieAuthenticationOptions.Value.Cookie;

That gives ".AspNetCore." instead of "foo". That object's other properties are also wrong, they all seem to be default values.
Why is this happening, and how do I get a valid instance of that options object?

Could you put the cookie name in appsettings.json and just refer to IConfiguration in both places?

@BenderBoy Thanks. I'm doing something like that - out of necessity. But it's a hack and I'd like to avoid it. Also, all the other cookie config settings are set to their defaults. I'm very surprised this doesn't work.

Have you tried injecting CookieAuthenticationOptions instead of IOptions?

ASP.NET Core Identity uses a named IOptions approach, but the default IOptions DI provides a default, unnamed instance of (in this case) CookieAuthenticationOptions. That means the instance you get from DI is different to the one configured using ConfigureApplicationCookie.
To access a named instance of IOptions, you can use either IOptionsSnapshot or IOptionsMonitor (docs). Here's an example of how to access the ASP.NET Core Identity instance of CookieAuthenticationOptions:

Inject IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions> into the controller's constructor.

In the action, use the following code:
var cookieName = cookieAuthenticationOptions
   .Get(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)
   .Cookie.Name;




Thanks, that worked. Whenever I need startup config I typically inject IOptions<T>, so I did so here too. I didn't consider the naming issue.

I'm curious, is it possible to know which options objects are named and which are not? How did you know, in this case, that the options object I needed was one of the named ones? (I suppose one could simply try both ways, if one is aware of this "gotcha".)

I've come across this before when working with AuthN, which has the concept of scheme names and therefore requires the ability to configure multiple instances. Specifically here, ConfigureApplicationCookie uses an overload of...

IServiceCollection.Configure, which takes the name of the options. Generally, I don't think named options are used all that much, so it's likely you won't come across this often.
